# How can I change the position of the text in a plot

Tags: r, text, plot

I would like to add Intercept and coeff to my plot.I tried to do it manually by using this code:

```
text(5.0, 150, paste("Intercept = 16.12 ", "Coef = 0.06", sep = ''), pos = 3)
```

But as you can see from the picture it is too up.![regression line][1]How can I control the position better?
 is there a way to insert the Intercept and the coef to the plot by using the the `lm` results without entering the values manually?

Comment: You can try using the `adj` argument in `text()` which positions the text somewhere in the plot relative to the plotting area (e.g. try `adj = c(0, 0)` and remove the `pos` argument to see what that does; you may also have to play around with the coordinates you specify). To print the intercept and slope just substitute the hard-coded values in your `paste` function with the actual ones you get from your lm object (e.g if that is called m, you can call m$coefficients or coef(m))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the results

```
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
m <- lm(y~x)
```

the coefficients with intersept can be found:

```
m$coefficients[1]
m$coefficients[2]
```

As about adding text, you should just give another coordinates to the text function or maybe use

```
legend("topleft",...)
```

it will give nice results.